# Better to use size or count on collection?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql-9.1

When counting a collection. Is it better to do it via size or count?

Size = Ruby (`@foobars.size`)

Count = SQL (`@foobars.count`)

I also notice, `count` makes another trip to the db.

Comment: i use `count` if that is the only information needed, but if I am going to iterate through the collection i use `length` (size is alias for length) and avoid the extra db call

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tend to suggest using `size` for everything, just because it's safer. People make fewer silly mistakes using `size`.

Here's how they work:

`length`: length will return the number of elements from an array, or otherwise loaded collection - the key point is that the collection will be loaded here regardless. So if you're working with an activerecord association, it will pull the elements from the DB to memory, and then return the number.

`count`: count issues a database query, so if you have an array already it's a pointless call to your database.

`size`: best of both worlds - size checks which type you're using and then uses whichever seems more appropriate (so if you have an array, it will use length; if you have an unretrieved `ActiveRecord::Association` it will use count, and so on).

Source:
http://blog.hasmanythrough.com/2008/2/27/count-length-size/

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the situation. In the example you show I would go with `size` since you already have the collection loaded and a call to `size` will just check the length of the array. As you noticed, `count` will do an extra db query and you really want to avoid that.

However, in the scenario that you only want to display the number of Foobars and not show those objects, then I would go with `count` because it will not load the instances into memory, just return the number of records.